# Como consumir un csv e incluirla en una consulta where con Spark Scala

Tags: sql, csv, condiciones, scala, apache-spark

Estoy armando una consulta a una tabla .parquet con spark scala donde tengo una condicion (where) para obtener los registros que tengan el pais = peru o colombia. Por ejemplo:

```
val transform = path.select(
    col("continente"),
    col("pais"),
    col("columna_3")
    ...)

val condition = transform.where("continente = 'SUDAMERICA' AND (pais = 'PERU' OR pais = 'COLOMBIA')")

condition.show(50,false)
```

Sin embargo ahora necesito considerar una cantidad variable de paises en mi condición que estaran en un archivo .csv (repito este archivo csv va variar de cantidad de paises en el tiempo); no logro encontrar información de como incluir el contenido del .csv en la consulta, pero si se como leer el csv con:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.csv
spark.read.csv("path/csv")
```

Pero quisiera obtener en mi condicion algo como:

```
val condition = transform.where("continente = 'SUDAMERICA' AND (pais = '#paisesDelCsv')")
```

Un ejemplo del archivo .csv seria:

```
PERU,COLOMBIA,BRASIL,ECUADOR,ARGENTINA
```

Si alguien tiene alguna idea, o si se puede hacer de otro modo me gustaria saber sus opiniones...

Answer (score 0):

Trabajando con estos DataFrame de Ejemplos:

```
val paisesYContinentes = Seq(
    ("SUDAMERICA", "ARGENTINA"),
    ("EUROPA", "FRANCIA"),
    ("ASIA", "CHINA"),
    ("EUROPA", "ESPAÑA"),
    ("ASIA", "TAIWAN"),
    ("SUDAMERICA", "ECUADOR"),
    ("SUDAMERICA", "CHILE"),
    ("SUDAMERICA", "PERU"),
    ("SUDAMERICA", "COLOMBIA"),
    ("SUDAMERICA", "BRASIL")).toDF("continente", "pais")

 val paisesYContratosDataFrame = Seq(
    ("contract1", "PERU"),
    ("contract2", "COLOMBIA"),
    ("contract3", "COLOMBIA")).toDF("contrato", "pais")
```

Realicé una lista con los valores de la columna país y luego lo utilicé como condición en el where.

Genero la lista con los países del DataFrame que me interesa:

```
  val paises = paisesYContratosDataFrame.select("pais").collect().map(_(0)).toList
```

Realizo la transformación para quedarme con sólo con esos países y de manera dinámica:

```
  val transformConLista = transform.
                        where(col("continente") === "SUDAMERICA").
                        where(col("pais") isin (paises:_*))
```

Eso daría el mismo resultado que la consulta original que posteaste. De todas formas me preguntaba si no sería más útil que utilices Joins. Yo creo que en tu caso usaría un innerjoin. Buena respuesta en Stackoverflow: [Joining Spark dataframes on the key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40343625/joining-spark-dataframes-on-the-key/40345048)